# How to split a contour in opencv python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

the problem I'm facing currently is related to my code which is being developed to follow a black line. Currently my code function by creating a contour around the black line and drawing a dot in the centre of that line. I also draw a dot in the centre of the image and calculate the distance between those dots. With this information i can turn the robot accordingly.

[image: Example of current code]

What I want to achieve is to segment the contour horizontally as when there are steep corners in the line the code will calculate the average and the dot will be outside the line

[image]

This isn't the biggest issue in the world because I can just situate the camera to be closer to the line making the line curve less dramatic however, I don't wan to do this unless it's my last option as it's less efficient and not cool. This is an example of what i want the image to look like:

[image]

as you can see the contour is seperated into smaller contours.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

#lower and upper values in hsv format for mask
lg = np.array([75, 52, 60])
ug = np.array([106, 255, 255])

lb = np.array([0,32,0])
ub = np.array([179, 255, 93])

#ignore this (for seperate part of line following)
def percentage_calculator(boundaries, colour, image):

    for(lower, upper) in boundaries:

        lower = np.array(lower)
        upper = np.array(upper)

        # finds colors in boundaries a applies a mask
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
        output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

        tot_pixel = image.size
        pixel = np.count_nonzero(output)
        percentage = round(pixel * 100 / tot_pixel, 2)

        print(colour + " pixels: " + str(pixel))
        print("Total pixels: " + str(tot_pixel))
        print("Percentage of " + colour + " pixels: " + str(percentage) + "%")

green_boundaries = [
    ([75, 52, 60], [106, 255, 255])
    ]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#centre point of screen
Xmid = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) / 2)
Ymid = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) / 2)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #cropping and getting the hsv value and converting it to see of the value is there for green
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lg, ug)
    green_result = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask)

    #cropping and getting the hsv value and converting it to see of the value is there
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lb, ub)
    black_result = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask1)
    
    #Finding all current contours
    contours,_= cv2.findContours(mask1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    #finding the biggest contour
    max_contour = contours[0]
    for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour)>cv2.contourArea(max_contour):
                max_contour = contour
    
    #simplifying the contour so it approximates the lines better
    contour = cv2.approxPolyDP(max_contour, 0.05 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)

    #calculating the centroid (I think) of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    
    #cX and cY are the centre of the contour
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(img, (Xmid, Ymid), 5, (255, 255, 0), -1)
    
    #drawing a line between the two circles for visualisation
    cv2.line(img, (cX, cY), (Xmid, Ymid), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    
    #using distance formula to find the distance between the two coords of the circles
    distance = math.sqrt((Xmid - cX) ** 2 + (Ymid - cY) ** 2)
    
    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                
    #cv2.imshow("green", green_result)
    cv2.imshow('black', black_result)
    #cv2.imshow("hsv", hsv)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You can get the medial axis (skeleton) of the black region from the contour or just the thresholded image. Then pick your point on the skeleton.  See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html

Comment: needs moar lowpass -- that splitting you want can be achieved by working on ROIs of the whole picture

Comment: You can try not to use contours, but to use the centroid (center of mass) of the inverted image.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried using the sickit-image skeleton but I have only found it being plotted in matplotlib which is not what i want. I tried using https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/3913ab49d344fac4d02bcc887ba4277d to get the skeleton but have some dots around the main line which could affect the line following. Not sure yet but I'll update the question to have an image of what I'm talking about

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I had a look at moar lowpass and found it's a smoothing technique. Not sure how this would help me but I would appreciate a longer explanation.

Comment: that is, if you're bothered by the frills on your contours and want to reduce the number of "noise" components. also, you don't need contours at all, just a bunch of masks. `cv.moments()` works on masks just fine. calculating contours is a waste of time here.

Comment: “*I tried using the sickit-image skeleton but I have only found it being plotted in matplotlib*” The operation outputs an image as a NumPy array, which is the same format that OpenCV uses. I don’t understand why you think the output is necessary a plot. Don’t use that repo you found, it’s bad code.

Comment: If you want help, post your original image without the green lines.

Comment: @fmw42 that would be great, I can always use some help. https://github.com/Noah-Robb/Line-Following-Image, I've uploaded some example images of the line and two of my previous codes for reference. Even just a comment on both codes would be helpful. I might not be able to respond very frequently as it's end on semester and I have no spare time. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to split a contour, however, here is the best solution I found to get the middle of the line. I converted the image to grayscale and blurred the image:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9)
```

I thresholded and inverted the image to get the black line as the only non-zero pixels:

```
_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
inverted_thresholded = cv2.bitwise_not(thresholded)
```

I then eroded those pixels with skimage's skeletonization and grabbed all the pixels left:

```
skeleton, dist = medial_axis(inverted_thresholded, return_distance=True)
dist_on_skel = dist * skeleton
skeleton = (255 * dist_on_skel).astype(np.uint8)
Line = cv2.findNonZero(skeleton)
```

Then I remove any random noise by only grabbing pixels that are close to each other:

```
filtered_pixel_coords = []
prev_point = None

for pixel in Line:
    x, y = pixel[0]
    
    if prev_point is not None:
        prev_x, prev_y = prev_point
        distance = math.sqrt((x - prev_x) ** 2 + (y - prev_y) ** 2)
        
        if distance <= outlier_threshold:
            #forgets about any pixels on the edge cause sometimes there are a lot of them and that is bad
            if 10 < x < w - 10 and 10 < y < h - 10:
                filtered_pixel_coords.append([x, y])
    else:
        filtered_pixel_coords.append([x, y])

    prev_point = [x, y]

pixel_Coords = filtered_pixel_coords
```

I then draw a line between the average of every 50th pixel:

```
for i, coord in enumerate(pixel_Coords):
    avg[0] += coord[0]
    avg[1] += coord[1]
    count += 1

    if count == 50 or i == len(pixel_Coords) - 1:
        avg[0] //= count
        avg[1] //= count
        averaged_coords.append(avg.copy())
        avg = [0, 0]
        count = 0

for i in range(len(averaged_coords) - 1):
    pt1 = (averaged_coords[i][0], averaged_coords[i][1])
    pt2 = (averaged_coords[i + 1][0], averaged_coords[i + 1][1])
    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to skeletonize using Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

img = cv2.imread("WIN_20230617_22_11_44_Pro.jpg")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert so lines are white
thresh = 255 - thresh

# then skeletonize thresh in range 0 to 1 as float32, then convert back to uint8
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(thresh.astype(np.float32)/255)
skeleton = (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("WIN_20230617_22_11_44_Pro_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("WIN_20230617_22_11_44_Pro_skeleteon.jpg", skeleton)

# show results
cv2.imshow("threshold", thresh)
cv2.imshow("skeleton", skeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Skeleton Image:

[image]